# ¿Saltar la entrada de contraseña en servidor sftp en cmd? (Windows)

Tags: windows, cmd, sftp

Tengo un servidor y quiero ingresar con sftp y descargar archivos por medio del cmd, hice un archivo .bat en el que especifico

```
sftp username@host
get \Out\* D:\pruebas
bye
pause
```

pero cuando ingreso por el archivo .bat siempre me pide contraseña el cmd y no se como quitarle esa contraseña o saltarme ese login para poder hacer la descarga automatica. Netamente es para que el usuario no tenga que ingresar nada de usuarios ni contraseñas.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Pero en ese caso no deberias sacar la contraseña del lado del servidor?

Comment: Pide la contraseña del FTP? Podrías ponerla en la conexión al ftp, pero suena a una práctica insegura

Comment: Yo usaría una key ssh, puedes ver más aquí: https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/use-ssh-keys-authentication/

Comment: sftp es un protocolo seguro de ftp por eso pide contraseña

Comment: puede ir a la siguiente pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386482/how-to-run-the-sftp-command-with-a-password-from-bash-script